# Xcode 4.2 Wirelessly connected devices

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, wireless

I got my device to sync wirelessly with iTunes and the devices shows up in the organizer. The only problem is that the dot next to it is yellow and I get a message saying "Unable to read from device".

When I plug it in, it works just fine, but trying to access it wirelessly doesn't.

Anyone ever run into that kind of problem before? If so, what did you do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. All information that I have read, and from what I have seen, the feature isn't fully ready to be used. Hopefully Apple will have this ready in the next iteration of Xcode. For now, it serves as a teaser of things to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha! I think I figured it out. The reason why I couldn't sync wirelessly with Xcode is because iTunes was syncing everything BUT apps. Your iTunes needs to be syncing your apps in order for Xcode to push apps to it. It makes sense when you think about it... :)

Let me know if that works for you too!